# How do I get the user_id after login wordpress/woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I have an application in codigniter where I only use a database table of the woocommerce `order_items`, where I only handle completed orders, now I want to get the user id as soon as it logs in to check my order_items table if the user has any orders completed , if he have finished order then open a popup to confirm the order, if he do not have finished order then log in normally.

I can not get the user id, any ideas for this case?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) { 
    $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false ); 
    wp_set_current_user ( $user_id );
}

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])){ 
    $redirect_to = 'localhost/meumerkado/valida_encomendas/…'; 
    return $redirect_to; 
} else { 
    $redirect_to = 'localhost/meumerkado/valida_encomendas/…'; 
    return $redirect_to; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? Please share your code

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
   function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
 $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
     wp_set_current_user ( $user_id );

Comment: if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['id'])){
        
  $redirect_to = 'http://localhost/meumerkado/valida_encomendas/'.$wp_query->query_vars['id'];
        return $redirect_to;
} else
 {
   $redirect_to = 'http://localhost/meumerkado/valida_encomendas/?id='.get_current_user_id();
         return $redirect_to;
 }
   }